# Use $strLenCP with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have this mongodb query

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(
    [{
        $project: {
            length: {
                $strLenCP: "$prefix"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            length: -1
        }
    }]
)
```

that I want to use into a spring java project but I can't manage to write the correct java code (the sort is not the issue).

I tried this

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(project().andExpression("strLenCP(prefix)").as("prefixLength"));
AggregationResults < RequestSettingsWithPrefixLength > results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, RequestSettings.class, RequestSettingsWithPrefixLength.class);
List < RequestSettingsWithPrefixLength > requestSettingsList = results.getMappedResults();
```

but I am getting a null key in agg JSON (debug mode):

```
{
    "aggregate": "__collection__",
    "pipeline": [{
        {
            "$project": {
                "prefixLength": {
                    "null": ["$prefix"]
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I can see that my agg object has this projection operation:

```
expression -> strLenCP(prefix)
field -> AggregationField: AggregationField - name: prefixLength,  target: prefixLength, synthetic: true
params -> []
```

I am not sure this is correct but I can't find any documentation that uses strLenCP.
I only found this test that uses the strLenCP projection:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/dc57b66adfd60b4d69d1d349b4fcfa4ab0da95e7/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/SpelExpressionTransformerUnitTests.java#L922

Could someone help please?

Cheers

Comment: thanks @Sagar Reddy for formatting

Comment: Np. What version of spring-mongo-db are you on ?

Comment: mongo-java-driver version is 3.4.0 and org.springframework.data is 1.9.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for Mongo3.4 aggregation operators were added in 1.10.0.RC1. If you are okay with updating to release candidate version everything should just work fine.

Or you can try the following but you'll need to use 1.8.5 version.

```
 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
  project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
      @Override
      public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
          return new BasicDBObject("$strLenCP", "$prefix");
      }
  }).as("prefixLength")
 );
```

Comment: 1.10.0 RC1 adds aggregation operators as API and exposes several aggregation expressions via [SpEL support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/pull/243/commits/8b407165d9f1999a146daf7bf0088c768c075415#diff-a646e0988d082bfbb13a36e8760b1b74R233).

Comment: many thanks @Sagar Reddy, the DBObject solution works perfectly. I can't use RC as the code I am writing is needed very soon in production but I will update when available

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression `project(...).and(valueOf("fieldName").lengthCP()).as("fieldLength")`

Answer (score 0):

@kairius answer isn't clear. This is how it should be done: Use `StringOperators#valueOf` followed by `lengthCP()`:

```
TypedAggregation.project()
    .and(StringOperators.valueOf("prefix").lengthCP())
    .as("length")
```