# How to project $strLenCP in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongoDB aggregate query using which i was able to get the length of the field which has max no of characters in the collection. I need help to convert that aggregate query to its equivalent in java.
Please find the aggregate query below:

```
db.getCollection('staff').aggregate([
{"$match": {"department": "technology"}},
{"$project": {"maxCharLength": {"$strLenCP": "$firstName"}}},
{"$sort": {"maxCharLength": -1}},{"$limit":  1}
])
```

I need to convert the above query to its equivalent in java. Please find the java code which im trying below: Im stuck with on how to use $strLenCP with project in java code below:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
      match(Criteria.where("department").in("technology")),
project(""), //how to  use  $strLenCP here
sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "maxCharLength"),
limit(1));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "staff", Staff.class);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use $strLenCP with Spring Data MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550451/use-strlencp-with-spring-data-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Aggregation.project("firstName").andExpression("strLenCP(firstName)").as("length")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.